# How I can detect that the main code is not changed but the md files are in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Actually my question is quite clear and understandable. In my project, which I keep up to date via Git, I want Jenkins to skip the build process when I change only the parts of the documentations (main code will not be changed) such as readme. How can I do this?

Comment: [Polling ignores changes in certain paths](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#plugin-content-polling-ignores-commits-in-certain-paths) ?

Comment: Do you want the entire build to be skipped (not even start) or do you want to skip a specific build stage?

Comment: Sorry for late answer, I can skipped specified stages but honestly I want to skip all stages and don't want build anything.